# Why is the derivative of $x^x$ not $x^x$?

Tags: calculus, derivatives

There is something called the "power rule" which indicates that the derivative of $x^a$ is $a*x^{(a-1)}$. Using the power rule, we would get that the derivative of $x^x$ is $x^x$:
$$\frac{d}{dx}x^x=x*x^{(x-1)}=x^x$$
But apparently, the derivative of $x^x$ is actually $x^x(\ln(x)+1)$, according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=derivative%20of%20x%5Ex). They used some other method using logs. Why is the "power rule" invalid in this case?

Comment: Because the power is not constant (and the derivative should captures its variation too).

Comment: Power rule applies only to constant $a$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You cannot use the power rule because the exponent is not a constant. You also cannot use the rule for exponentials because the base is not constant.

The trick is to express $x^x$ as an exponential function so that there will be no conflict of rules. $$x^x = e^{x\ln x}.$$
Now, you can apply the derivative.$$\frac{d}{dx}x^x = \frac{d}{dx}e^{x\ln x} = e^{x \ln x} \frac{d}{dx}(x\ln x) = x^x \frac{d}{dx}(x\ln x).$$ This is the answer given by Wolfram Alpha.